# In Python, can an object have another object as an attribute?

Tags: python, oop

In Python, can an object have another object as an attribute?  For example, can a class called *car* have a class called *tire* as an attribute?

Comment: That's the only thing you can have as attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean a class `tire` or an instance of class `tire`? It can have both although the latter is probably more useful. If you're looking for an **object** of class `Mary` to **has-a** object of type `Fred` you'd want the `classinst` variety of assignment:

```
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:09:56) 
>>> class Fred(object): pass
... 
>>> class Mary(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.classref = Fred
...         self.classinst = Fred()
... 
>>> x = Mary()
>>> dir(x)
[... 'classinst', 'classref']
>>> x.classref
<class '__main__.Fred'>
>>> x.classinst
<__main__.Fred object at 0xb76eed0c>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

```
>>> class tire:
...     pass
...
>>> class car:
...     def __init__(self, tire):
...             self.tire = tire
...
>>> t = tire()
>>> t.brand = 'Goodyear'
>>> c = car(t)
>>> c.tire.brand
'Goodyear'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have both instances and classes as attributes of both classes and instances -- all four combinations work just fine (and can be combined freely).  However, do keep in mind the distinction between a *class* and an *instance* thereof -- the way you phrase your question suggests some confusion.  Anyway, taking your question literally:

> can a class called car have a class
>   called tire as an attribute?

```
class tire(object):
    ...class body here...

class car(object):
    thetire = tire
    ...rest of class body here...
```

A `tire = tire` assignment in the body of `car` would not work (naming confusion!-) so you need to name the class attribute differently than the class that's its value.  (This does not apply to *instance* attributes, since their syntax, e.g. `self.tire`, is that of *qualified* names, not barenames, so there's no naming confusion -- only to *class* attributes).  Was that perchance the source of the problem that led you to ask this question?

Answer (score 0):

Sure; classes, like any other value, can be either class or instance attributes:

```
class A(object):
    pass

class B(object):
    class_attr = A

    def __init__(self):
        self.instance_attr = A
```

With this code, you could use `B.class_attr` or `B().instance_attr` to access `A`.